# Need help on Azure policy for Azure Iot Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-policy

I am defining deployifnotexits policies for my organization, I have defined policies for Azure IoT Hub, when creating private end points, 2 private dns zone groups are created as shown below:

```
Azure IoT Hub (Microsoft.Devices/IotHubs)/iotHub 
1. privatelink.azure-devices.net    
2. privatelink.servicebus.windows.net

        Once I create an endpoint with IotHub, policy is getting executed, but I only see A record for azure-devices.net, but not for service bus
```

Comment: Where's the question exactly? The problem? The question is not clear.

Comment: Question is I get only one A record for privatelink.azure-devices.net when a deployifnotexists is created and not for privatelink.servicebus.windows.net. I am using Arm template to deploy policy. I can share the code if it's needed